# How can I upload the csv files from Lambda to an S3 bucket? "[ERROR] KeyError: 'Records' and my lambda function is also not getting triggered by s3

Tags: python, excel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I extracted an Excel file with multiple sheets from S3 and I am turning each sheet  into csv format and doing a simple cleansing before uploading it to another S3 bucket.

This is my code so far for my Lambda function but I have no idea how to upload the csv file for each sheet to S3.

Also I want to change the empty cells in the excel files with `Nan` but I don't know how.

Update: I tried the solution from the answer below. I am getting "errorMessage": "'Records'", "errorType": "KeyError". My lambda function is also not getting triggered by s3.

Comment: How have you configured the trigger? Did you do it in the S3 management console? Can you show us the configuration?

Comment: I added the trigger in my lambda function as s3 with the bucket name I want to extract the excel file from with the event type all objects create events

Comment: You can configure the trigger either from the S3 bucket, or within the Lambda function console. What makes you think that the function is not being triggered? What is showing in Amazon CloudWatch Logs for the function? ([Accessing Amazon CloudWatch Logs for AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html))

Comment: It doesn't show anything on CloudWatch Logs that is why I believe it's not being triggered. Maybe it's due to the error that it is giving me 'Records'

Comment: Make sure that the role assigned to the Lambda function has the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` policy, which grants permission to write to CloudWatch Logs. If that doesn't help, then configure the trigger **from the S3 management console** to make sure it is correctly configured. Also, look in the Lambda **monitoring tab** to see whether there have been any invocations of the function. Failing ALL that, I would recommend temporarily creating a new function that simply logs a message to CloudWatch Logs, configuring the trigger and confirming it works. Then, compare it to your existing function.

Answer (score 0):

You can store files in Lambda's local file system within the `/tmp/` directory. There is a limit of 500MB, so delete those files once you have finished with them.

Therefore, when you are creating a file, put it in that directory:

```
with open("/tmp/data%s.csv" %(sheet6.name.replace(" ","")), "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
```

You can then upload it to Amazon S3 by using [`upload_file(file, bucket, key)`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file):

```
s3.upload_file('/tmp/data1.csv', 'mybucket', 'data1.csv')
```

Here's some code I have for extracting the Bucket and Key that triggered a Lambda function:

```py
import urllib

def lambda_handler(event, context):

  bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
  key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
  ...
```